# Java - Move image to old coordinates after rotating

Tags: java, rotation, coordinates

After I saw this Website [here](https://www.siggraph.org/education/materials/HyperGraph/modeling/mod_tran/2drota.htm) I tried to use it as good as I could. I want to rotate my image by 90 degrees and have it at the same position as before the rotation. I tried it like this:

```
            int xold = charX;
            int yold = charY;
            charX = 0;
            charY = 0;
            //g.drawImage(man, charX, charY, man.getWidth(), Man.getHeight(), null); -> I have tried it with and without this line.
            g.rotate(Math.toRadians(90)); //After I moved the picture to (0, 0) I rotate it by 90°.
            charX = xold; //After this I move the (rotated) picture to the old place
            charY = yold;
            g.drawImage(man, charX, charY, man.getWidth(), man.getHeight(), null); //And finally I print int using my Graphics2D object
```

Well something must be wrong. If I now execute this code, the picture just dissapears and finally returns in its old state.

Does somebody get the mistake?

Comment: what happens if you comment out the last line

Comment: Nothing of course - How can it be supposed to output the image without drawing it?